# How did my process exit?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

From C# on a Windows box, is there a way to find out how a process was stopped? 
I've had a look at the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, managed to get a nice friendly callback from the Exited event once I set `EnableRaisingEvents = true;` but I have not managed to find out whether the process was killed or whether it exited naturally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire up Process Monitor (from Sysinternals, part of Microsoft), run your process and let it die, then filter the Process Monitor results by your process name -- you will be able to see everything that it did, including exit codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return code of the process for that. If your process returns a non-zero value from its Main method, you can then check whether or not the process exited by itself (the return value matches).